# Drop Down menu in PHP

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I want to add a drop down menu in my Php form (backend: postgresql):

I want to display supplier details in a drop down fashion: 
Suppliers are 1. Nasik, 2. Hyderabad, 3. Officer

My Code:

```
<tr>
<td class="lbl_Fonts" height="30">Supplier<font color="red"> *</font> </td>
<td colspan="1">
 <select name="cmbStamp" onChange="" style="width:200px;" >
 <option value='' > SELECT </option>
 <?php
        $sql= "select supplier_name from supplier_details";
        $row =$conn->Exec($sql);
        while(odbc_fetch_into($row,$Record))
        {
         echo "<option value ='" .trim($Record[0]). "'>" . trim($Record[1]) . "</option>";
        }
        odbc_free_result($row);
  ?>
<td width="21%">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
```

Can any one help me where I have gone wrong, currently with this code it shows a blank drop down menu.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, the Q&A site. Q&A = Question&Answer. I can see no question.

Comment: Perhaps no rows are being returned and hence no `option` tags are being created

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried?

There is no error checking in your code.

One of the reasons it's not behaving as you expect is that you only select one field from the database (supplier_name) but are trying to add 2 into your form ($Record[0], $Record[1]). If everything else were working then this should be obvious from viewing the source html generated.

Your code doesn't show any initialization of $conn, anf there's no closing element for the select.

Comment: ya, that was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Include this `</select>`  in your code

```
<tr>
    <td class="lbl_Fonts" height="30">Supplier<font color="red"> *</font> </td>
    <td colspan="1">
     <select name="cmbStamp" onChange="" style="width:200px;" >
     <option value='' > SELECT </option>
     <?php
            $sql= "select supplier_name from supplier_details";
            $row =$conn->Exec($sql);
            while(odbc_fetch_into($row,$Record))
            {
             echo "<option value ='" .trim($Record[0]). "'>" . trim($Record[1]) . "</option>";
            }
            odbc_free_result($row);
      ?>
    </select>
    <td width="21%">&nbsp;</td>

 </tr>
```

Comment: I have closed tags, it might have been missed while copying here. .

Answer (score 0):

close the tag select , and try to  write

```
<?php
    $sql= "select supplier_name from supplier_details";
    $row =$conn->Exec($sql);
    while(odbc_fetch_into($row,$Record))
    {?>
     <option value ="<?php echo trim($Record[0])?>"><?php echo trim($Record[1])?></option>
<?php
    }
    odbc_free_result($row);
?>
</select>
```

Comment: I have closed the tags, it might have been missed while copying..